# HTTP post didn't get response in json Android2.2 version?

Tags: android

Hi i didn't get response `Android 2.2` version but perfectly working `4.0 version`.

my code is below:

```
HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        System.out.println("**************Request=>"+urlEncodedFormEntity.toString());
        method.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
        HttpResponse response = executeMethod(method);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity!=null) {
            String value = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.i("", "Meesage"+value);

        }
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```

While running 2.2 version i got this type of Log cat message

```
04-01 11:41:12.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(13719): Can't open keycharmap file
04-01 11:41:12.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(13719): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/sec_touchscreen_.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='sec_touchscreen '
04-01 11:41:12.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(13719): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Please give me solution?

Comment: plz post relevant logcat result and make sure you are using Background Thread for making httpprequest from Main UI Thread

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the http request.  The problem is elsewhere

Comment: you got any responce or not?? you you debug your code??

Comment: I can't understand else where means?

Comment: I didn't get any response in 2.2 version only but it's perfectly working 4.0 version.I have edit my question please see that i have mention log cat message also

Comment: are you testing on device or emulator?

Comment: change this line :String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"UTF-8")

Comment: what is meaning UTF-8 this is version

Comment: I fount it this line skipped 2.2 version

Comment: response = client.execute(method);

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this way.

```
try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 20000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 2000);

        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("Your url");


        response = client.execute(post);

        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String a = convertStreamToString(in);
        //Log.v("Response", ""+a);

            } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


//Json response
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

              try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  response = client.execute(method);

Comment: @Gomathi Did you give strict mode thread policy for Android 4.0 version.

Comment: I fount it this line skipped in 2.2 version response = client.execute(method);